# React testing for the TextField element from Material UI

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I'm trying to do npm test on a Textfield element, and this is what my Textfield element looks like:

```
                        <TextField
                            inputProps ={{"data-testid": "testId"}}
                            title='titleInput'
                            label="Textbook Title*"
                            variant="filled"
                            fullWidth
                            style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                            value={this.state.title}
                            onChange={this.handleTitleChange}
                            autoFocus
                        />
```

and this is what my test looks like:

```
export const selectMaterialUiSelectOption = async (element, optionText) =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      // The the button that opens the dropdown, which is a sibling of the input
      const selectButton = element.parentNode.querySelector('[role=button]');

      // Open the select dropdown
      UserEvent.click(selectButton);

      // Get the dropdown element. We don't use getByRole() because it includes <select>s too.
      const listbox = document.body.querySelector('ul[role=listbox]');

      // Click the list item
      const listItem = within(listbox).getByText(optionText);
      UserEvent.click(listItem);

      // Wait for the listbox to be removed, so it isn't visible in subsequent calls
      waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => document.body.querySelector('ul[role=listbox]')).then(
          resolve,
      );
    });
```

```
describe("Render Testing of EditListing Page", () =>{
  test("Basic Render Test of EditListing Page", () => {
    render(<EditListing />);
  });
  test("Render Listing Text", () =>{
    selectMaterialUiSelectOption(getByTestId('testId'))
      }
  )
```

However, it's giving me this error:

```
  ● Render Testing of EditListing Page › Render Listing Text

    TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got string.

      481 |   });
      482 |   test("Render Listing Text", () =>{
    > 483 |     selectMaterialUiSelectOption(getByTestId('testId'), "10")
          |                                  ^
      484 |       }
      485 |   )
      486 |
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to render your component also in your second test, and you can get the `getByTestId` from the returned object:

```js
describe("Render Testing of EditListing Page", () => {
  test("Basic Render Test of EditListing Page", () => {
    render(<EditListing />);
  });
  test("Render Listing Text", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<EditListing />);
    await selectMaterialUiSelectOption(getByTestId("testId"));
  });
});
```